# Docker Compose - Connection to Phpmyadmin and MysQL not working

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I need a simple way with Docker-compose to create an environment with PHP, NGINX, MySQL and phpmyadmin.

I have already successfully created the PHP environment with NGINX.

Now I want to add a database with MySQL and phpmyadmin. These two components do not seem to work. For example, I cannot reach phpmyadmin through the specified port "8081". I reach my local servers with my local IP addresses and the ports at the end of the address.

As soon as I want to call phpmyadmin the browser window tells me "Can't connect to server".

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        links:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        image: php:8-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql
        environment:
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '<mypassword>'
              MYSQL_DATABASE: baton
              MYSQL_USER: baton
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: '<mypassword>'
        ports:
              - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
              - ./database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: pma
        links:
              - mysql
        environment:
              PMA_HOST: mysql
              PMA_PORT: 3306
              PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        restart: always
        ports:
              - 8081:80
```

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: You are setting username and password in the mysql container, but are *not* setting them in the phpmyadmin container. Think you need to do that, right? There seems to be PMA_USER and PMA_PASSWORD environment variables for the phpmyadmin image.

Comment: `docker-compose logs phpmyadmin` would probably help you to debug this problem further.

Comment: @thephper username and password are not required to be defined for phpMyAdmin; it will prompt the user from the login page.

Comment: @Maddin this docker-compose.yml worked for me. Perhaps you need to recreate the containers or reset your database, something seems to be odd there.

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch I recreated the containers and I have made a reset with the database. Nothing helped. Every time there is the connection error. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: I used the command "docker-compose logs phpmyadmin". There were several lines with the same output: pma           | standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Comment: Do you happen to be running this on an arm64 architecture machine?

Comment: Yes, on arm64. Now I found a new docker image for arm64: hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/phpmyadmin . Now I see the login screen of phpmyadmin. But I can not connect to the server url. How can I find out the correct server url for the mysql database?

Comment: The server hostname is defined through Docker Compose networking; it's the hostname assigned through your docker-compose.yml file — in your case, `mysql`. You'll have to make sure the MySQL host has a user created that allows connections from an external host (you should be able to use the phpMyAdmin hostname here, `phpmyadmin` in your case, but also the wildcard `%` would work since networking is disallowed outside of this Docker group). I would remove the `PMA_ARBITRARY` variable because you've already defined the server with `PMA_HOST` and don't need to connect to other arbitrary hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the mistake I made to connect to the database via phpmyadmin. I got a second database, which already running on port 3306. I now switched to the existing database and now the connection works!